# Ajax request Canceled in Tizen's emulator, but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tizen, tizen-emulator

I currently have an error with my tizen emulator when I try to contact a `webservice` through `$.getJSON`.

I have a button, when I click on it, I get the JSON from a `webservice`, simple as that. On my computer browser, this works perfectly, but when I run the code as an app on Tizen's emulator (gear), the `GET` method returns : (canceled)
`Request cancelled`.

Here's the code (main.js):

```
$(window).load(function(){document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
    if(e.keyName == "back")
        tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
});
$('.button').click(function(){
    callWebService();//Calls webservice
    return false;
});

function callWebService(){
    //Works on desktop's Chrome
    $.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan", function( data ) {
          $('#ol_home_products').html(data.result);
        })
        .fail(function( err ) {
            //Never called
            console.log( err );
        });
}
});
```

I can see the cancel error in Networks's tab, but nothing shows up in Console.
I don't know where the problem is in Tizen gear emulator, the code works perfectly in browser.

Thanks.

EDIT : This is my config.xml, the privilege internet is here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/myApp" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
<tizen:application id="jVqvRz7h1V.myApp" package="jVqvRz7h1V" required_version="2.2"/>
<content src="index.html"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<name>myApp</name>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

Comment: I got the solution from Tizen developers' forums. I didn't set the Internet persmission and the access domain in config.xml.
Here's the correct file : 
<code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from Tizen developers' forums. I didn't set the Internet privilege and the access domain in `config.xml`.

Here's the correct file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/myApp" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="jVqvRz7h1V.myApp" package="jVqvRz7h1V" required_version="2.2"/>
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>myApp</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
</widget>
```